# Justifying a Natural Isomorphism Claim Involving Limits and Colimits

Tags: category-theory

From *Categories for the Working Mathematician* pg. 68-69:

[image]
[image]

**Question:** What in particular justifies the natural isomorphism claims of (2) and (3)? What are the full functors that the natural isomorphism is from?

Comment: If you reformulate "universal arrow" in terms of representability as described elsewhere in Categories for the Working Mathematician, you'll see this is literally just the definition of limit in terms of representability. So the natural isomorphism claim comes from the general claim (elsewhere) that universal arrows and representability are the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Developing a little bit on Derek Elkins'comment above, for each small category $\mathbf C$ you can consider the functor 
$$P=\text{Nat}[F,\Delta-] \colon \mathbf C \longrightarrow \mathbf {Set}$$ 
that sends each object $c \in \mathbf C_0$ in $P(c)=\text{Nat}[F,\Delta(c)]$ and each morphism $f \in \mathbf C_1$ in the function $P(f)=\text{Nat}[F,\Delta(f)]$.

You can observe that a colimit object per $F$ is nothing but a representing object for such functor. Indeed a colimit is given by:

- an object $\varinjlim F \in \mathbf C_0$
- a cone from $\varinjlim F$ to $F$, that is a $\tau \in \text{Nat}[F,\Delta(\varinjlim F)]=P(\varinjlim F)$

such that for each other pair $(c \in \mathbf C, \sigma \in P(c)=\text{Nat}[F,\Delta(c)])$ there is a unique $f \colon c \to \varinjlim F \in \mathbf C_1$ satisfying the equation
$$\sigma = \Delta(f) \circ \tau=\text{Nat}[F,\Delta(f)](\tau)=P(f)(\tau)\ .$$

This amounts to saying that $(\varinjlim F,\tau)$ is a universal object for $P$. By yoneda lemma we have family of isomorphisms
$$\text{Nat}[\mathbf C[c,-],P] \cong P(c)$$
natural in $c \in \mathbf C_0$ and $P \in [\mathbf C,\mathbf{Set}]$, these isomorphism associate to the colimit object $(\varinjlim F,\tau)$ the natural transformation 
$$\mathbf C[\varinjlim F,-] \longrightarrow P=\text{Nat}[F,\Delta-]$$
that to each $f \colon \varinjlim F \to c$ associates the object $P(f)(\tau)$.

The universal property for colimits states that this natural transformation is actually a biiection, hence it is a natural isomorphism and is the natural isomorphism you are looking for.

The converse also holds, that is every natural isomorphism of the form $\hom[c,-] \to P$ arise from a pair $(c,\sigma \in P(c))$ such that $(c,\sigma)$ is a colimit for $F$.

By duality the same (or to be correct the opposite) holds for limits too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is meant by $Nat[F, \Delta(f)]$? I'm confused here because $\Delta(f)$ is an arrow, not an object.

Comment: @user1770201 is the function from $\text{Nat}[F,\Delta(c)]$ to $\text{Nat}[F,\Delta(c')]$, where $f \colon c \to c'$, that maps each $\sigma \colon F \to \Delta(c)$ into the natural transformation $\Delta(f)\circ \sigma$. 

If you prefer, is the arrow part of the composite of the representable functor $\text{Nat}[F,-]$ with the functor $\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more simplistic approach: I'll consider (3) only. We have the diagram $\left \{ F_i \right \}_{i\in \Lambda}$ and a colimit cocone $(l,\lambda).$

For the moment, fix $c$. Then the claim is that there an isomorphism of sets,

$\phi_c:Nat(F,\Delta c)\to C(l, c)$.

But this is clear because  $Nat(F,\Delta c)$ is just the set of cocones from $F$ to $c$ and the definition of the colimit says precisely that there is a bijection between this set and the set of arrows $f: l\to c,\ $ defined as follows: $\phi_c$ maps the cocone $(c,\tau)$ to the unique $f:l\to c$ that satisfies $f\circ \lambda_i=\tau_i.$ Thus, $Nat(F,\Delta c)\cong C$(lim$F,c).$

Naturality follows by considering, for $f:c\to c'$, the square

\begin{array}{&&} 
Nat(F,\Delta c) & \stackrel{\phi_c}{\to}& C(\text{lim F},c) \\ 
\downarrow & & \downarrow  \\ 
 Nat(F,\Delta c')& \stackrel{\phi_{c'}}{\to} & C(\text{lim F},c')
\end{array}

which is seen to commute as soon as we apply the UMP of the colimit.

Comment: What does UMP stand for?

Comment: UMP = universal mapping property. The naturality square in my answer is actually a special instance of the lim/$\Delta $ adjunction and if you chase the diagrams, you will see that it commutes.

Comment: Is a UMP (Universal Mapping Property) the same thing as a [Universal Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property)?